# Best practice for initial loading in iOS app

Tags: ios, authentication

Just starting out iOS development.

When starting my app, I'd like it to check if the user has a known account and if they do, "login" by acquiring an access token and then display the main / first view. If they don't have an account or if login fails, they should be redirected to a login / registration screen.

Initially I thought I'd hide this process (check for account + call to get access token) behind a splash screen, but apparently this is [against Apples guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/launch-screen/). Is there a common / recommended way to do this on iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By referencing to [application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622921-application?language=objc) you can read that this method is good for initializing.

> Use this method (and the corresponding 
>   application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:  method) to complete your
>   app’s initialization and make any final tweaks. This method is called
>   after state restoration has occurred but before your app’s window and
>   other UI have been presented. At some point after this method returns,
>   the system calls another of your app delegate’s methods to move the
>   app to the active (foreground) state or the background state. This
>   method represents your last chance to process any keys in the
>   launchOptions dictionary. If you did not evaluate the keys in your
>   application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method, you should look at
>   them in this method and provide an appropriate response. Objects that
>   are not the app delegate can access the same launchOptions dictionary
>   values by observing the notification named 
>   UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification and accessing the
>   notification’s  userInfo  dictionary. That notification is sent
>   shortly after this method returns.

Answer (score 0):

There may be several ways. But using singleton for token and launching your app is one of the best ways. As you might not need to use that launcher class again. Just for checking user have token and if yes then show main view otherwise login view.

Hope it helps you !!